# Instantiate a Class dynamically via variable

Tags: javascript, mootools

How can I instantiate a class by throwing in a variable name? 
Consider this method inside a class:

```
animate: function(el, build) { 
        console.log(build.effect); 
        var animationClass = new build.effect(el,build); 
},
```

Build is an object containing lots of stuff, but most importantly an 
"effect".  This effect is the name of an independent animation class-- 
one is called "MarioKartMenu".

console.log(build.effect) prints out "MarioKartMenu". 
But of course I get: TypeError: Result of expression 'build.effect' [MarioKartMenu] is not a constructor.

If I trash the dynamism and just make the code as such:

```
animate: function(el, build) {
        var animationClass = new MarioKartMenu(el,build);
    },
```

It works just fine.  Is it possible to make it dynamic like I'm attempting to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the function `MarioKartMenu` is defined in the global scope, you can access it by its string name using:

```
window["MarioKartMenu"]
```

This works because all global variables are properties of the `window` object.

Given the above, you can implement what you want by using:

```
var menuConstructor = window[build.effect];
var animationClass = new menuConstructor(el, build);
```

Comment: Perfect, I had it a feeling it would look something like that.  Thank you.

Comment: if it is inside a js class you can use as **`this["MarioKartMenu"]`**. I was struck with this for a while and figured it out!!

Comment: Doesn't work inside an "class" scope. I've tried!

Answer (score 3):

Just assign the constructor to `build.effect` (not a string containing its name) and it should work:

```
animate = function(el, build) {
    var animationClass = new build.effect(el,build);
}
// ...

b = ...;
b.effect = MarioKartMenu;
animate(e, b);
```

Comment: Also good to know, but once again, I have no idea what others might name their animation classes, so I'd still be dealing with a string.  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you're saying though.

Comment: Somewhere the users of your class need to specify which effect to use. Can't they there give you the constructor function itself instead of a string with the constructor functions name in it?

I'm not sure how the interface is going to look like, but it seems like a user would do something like this: var FooMenu = {...}; setEffect("FooMenu");. I would suggest to not use a string but pass FooMenu directly: var FooMenu = {...}; setEffect(FooMenu);.

Comment: Very valid.  I'm going to explore this.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to use JavaScript's `eval()` operator, though I understand this is a less than elegant solution. (Soemthing like this: `var animationClass = eval("new "+build.effect+"(el, build)");` although I'm not sure that's correct as I haven't used `eval()` like this before.). Ayman's answer is a much better variation on this idea.

My second thought is that `MarioKartMenu` isn't suitably abstracted. So I'd build a simple class around it that takes the effect name as a third parameter and uses a `switch()` statement to select amongst all the available effects, instantiates the correct one and returns it.

Comment: Good suggestions.  In the end I have no idea what effects will be there, as the class calling the animation classes will be completely extendable to allow anybody to create and use their own animations.  So a switch statement wouldn't work.